# volume scatter in blender giving me a dark screen with some crazy amounts of fireflies

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

[image]

I have attached volume scatter node to the world volume. 
So What I have right here is a super simple scene where the light is coming from a spot lamp and falling on the ground.

Ok so in this picture the left tab is my viewport and the right one is my render tab.
You might have noticed how different two images really are. I wanted the same effect as in the viewport but even after increasing the number of samples does nothing for the actual render.
**What I have tried:**

- Increasing the number of samples(did not work)
- decreasing the volume density(it's 0.001 btw)(worked but only for the viewport)
- Increased Indirect light clamping(Did nothing for the render)
- tried different angles(same result from each angle)

Please help me if you can by telling me what the issue is and how I can fix it

[image]

Comment: Increase the intensity of the light.

Comment: How many samples did you use at maximum ?

Comment: 250 but no effect

Comment: actually that render came out with the spot lamp's strength at 100000W

Comment: can you tell me why the viewport render and the actual render are strikingly different?

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=YY6x57km" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.cg src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=YY6x57km" />](https://blend-eom/b/YY6x57km/)

Comment: @moonboots I have sent the link you can click and download the .blend file

Comment: your link doesn't work, you need to copy the URL of this page, past it then upload, then copy the link it will give you, or use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=k06v1qNl" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/k06v1qNl/)

Comment: this one might work

Comment: I don't think that the file is the same as the one you show, could you please share the exact same file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=ekWlQJSE" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ekWlQJSE/)

Comment: OK I'm sorry for troubling you since so long. This one is gonna work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a circle called circle.001 that you've parented to your lamp object (called Sphere). This circle obstructs your spot light. It won't cause any problem in the *Viewport* because you've disabled its visibility, but you've enabled it for *Renders*. So delete this object or disable its visibility for renders.

Also:

- Reset the *Compositor*.
- Don't use the *Volume Scatter* for the whole world, as you explain it looks like you can't use any other light than Spots if it's assigned to the whole world. Instead, create a cube that encompass your scene and give it the *Volume Scatter* node.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man you have literally saved my day

Comment: but seriously now that I know where I was wrong(thanks to you) I feel like stupid

Comment: no problem, it was not obvious, I just made an unhide to make sure something was not hiding the light, then I had to find the object, it was kind of hidden in the Outliner as well as it was the child of another object  ;)

Comment: yeah but thanks anyway man

Comment: No, NO I just found out that volumetric scattering works only with the light which comes off spot lamp and no other light source will show any effect while in presence of volumetrics. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/lighting/volumetric_lights.html

Comment: yes ok I deplugged the Volume Scatter of your world and found that it worked, didn't know about the fact that it worked only with Spots though, you should create a cube that encompass your scene and give it the Volume Scatter node

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Intel denoiser in compositing.

Under [View Layer Properties -> Passes -> Data] check the box for "Denoising Data". 
Then in the compositor, connect the noisy image slot with the image slot in the "Denoiser" filter.  This works pretty well for me.

Also increase the light intensity.

Comment: have already tried it and got just a like less grainier picture which is completely flat or in simple words it didn't help at all in fact made the matter worse. BTW thanks